# WPF - Get bound source object from ListView.SelectedItem

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, data-binding

I have a `ListView` item that is bound to a `List<MyObject>` collection. `MyObject` has various methods that I'd like to invoke, e.g. when a user selects an item from the `ListView` and then clicks on a button to perform an action on that individual `SelectedItem`.

XAML:

```
<ListView x:Name="lvMyListView">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Title" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding myProperty}"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Code:

```
// WPF window constructor
public MyWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    List<MyObject> myItems = new List<MyObject>();
    this.SourceInitialized += MyWindow_SourceInitialized;
    lvMyListView.ItemsSource = myItems;
}

// MyObject definition
class MyObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    ...
    public string myProperty { get; set; }
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        ...
    }
}

// Button event
private void myButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // MyObject currentItem = lvMyListView.SelectedItem;
    // currentItem.DoSomething();
}
```

How can I get the actual instance of `MyObject` that is being represented by `ListView.SelectedItem`?
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have read your question several times. It seems to me that you are mixing the MVVM and normal backend coding together and that is making your code hard to read and understand.

There are, I believe 2 ways you can access the object. If I get what you asked correctly. You can either cast :

```
MyObject currentItem = lvMyListView.SelectedItem as MyObject;
```

or use `lvMyListView.SelectedIndex` against your original list.

Also note that first option can be `null` if not selected and second one can be `-1` so add checks accordingly.

But, a better approach is to use MVVM and data binding altogether. It's longer than I can write here but you create a view model object and bind the selected item property of the list to one of it's properties also your button would trigger an action in the view model class. This is a better approach to WPF coding. So please check that out.

Comment: Hi thanks for the detailed answer. Are you referring to `BindingExpressions` or `Commands` by any chance?

Comment: Yes I do. These are syntax to implement an architecture approach called MVVM. With that instead of coding your logic in the `MyWindow.cs` file you create a ViewModel class and the logic is implemeted there regardless of the UI. Then the UI is bound to the VM. This is really short description but can give you a hint on where to start. Hope it helps you

Answer (score 0):

```
            //let me know if any bug come, make sure it's selectedItems.Count>0||!=-1
            //using getting selected object in IList
            IList rows = tbl_perListView.SelectedItems;

            //OR accessing DataGridRow,datarow,DataRowView properties (but this method is dirty needs lot of extra code)

            DataRowView row = (DataRowView)tbl_perListView.SelectedItems[0];
            string s = row["name"].ToString();
```